# Quantile function of Singh-Maddala

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, quantiles

I am trying to understand how to derive the quantile function from the cdf.
The Singh-Maddala cdf is 
[image]

Should i just solve for x ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes: that's what "deriving" the quantile function means, doesn't it?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#Definition) may help you see that the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 3):

In case you were still wondering, solving $F(x)=u$ in $x$ leads to $$ Q(u) = b\Big((1-u)^{-1/q}-1\Big)^{1/a},$$ where $u$ is a realisation of standard uniform variate. To generate Singh-Maddala random variates, $1-u$ can be replaced simply by $u$.